# How would one implement ambient listening in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, speech-recognition, ambient

I want to write a program that will start a thread when a is heard. I would imagine a grammar list might help to achieve this, but wouldn't the keyword be triggered all the time? (I only want the keyword to start a thread). I already have voice input ([link](https://github.com/The-Shadow/java-speech-api)) implemented but you need to send the audio sample to a server for analysis which would prove costly and impractical for ambient listening. Any suggestions?

Comment: Begin by researching java voice recognition libraries.  Asking for a comparison between libraries might get you more here, but I'd read reviews elsewhere too.

Comment: This is the current library I am using if it helps. [link](https://github.com/The-Shadow/java-speech-api)

Comment: Post it in your question